# how to rotate image?

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I had a hard time fixing this code.

```
UIGestureRecognizer *tapGest = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
tapIt = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGest;
[tapIt setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[tapIt setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
tapIt.delegate = self;
[pc1 addGestureRecognizer:tapIt];
```

I want to rotate it (the image) to another degree, example 0, 90, 180, 360 degrees. 
What do I have to add?

Comment: This piece of code has nothing to do with rotating images. Did you copy-pasted from a wrong place?

Comment: what will i do if i want to rotate a uiimage 0,90,180,360 degrees when tap?. can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

It is a tap recognizer, so the "tapped:" method will get called whenever you tap (double tap in your case) the specific view.

So inside the tapped: method you will change the rotation of the view by applying a rotation transform, like this:

```
- (void)tapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    // Rotate the view that was tapped to 90 degrees (pi/4)
    UIView *tappedView = [gesture view];
    [tappedView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_4)];
}
```

To rotate the view to another degree you would change the angle argument for the transform.

---

If you wanted the view to add 90 degrees every time it was tapped you could do this by rotating the existing transform of the view and then setting it again, like this:

```
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate([tappedView transform], M_PI_4);
[tappedView setTransform:newTransform];
```

Answer (score 1):

please, use the `UIImageView` class, set the `image` property of this class properly, add the `UIImageView` to your any `UIViewController`, and then **you have chance to rotate** the `UIImageView` using the the following method:

```
_imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(_angle);
```

*(please, don't forget the* `_angle` *must be in radian)*

to make the rest of the code (from where and when you get the parameter `_angle`) is still wanting for you.